# Procedure doesn't do anything

Tags: php, mysql, procedure

I made a procedure in mySql. It looks like this.

[image]

I called this procedure from php.

After this call the table still remains empty and I do not know why.

Problems that I have checked:

1. variable names
2. connection
3. syntax (I think is the right syntax)

UPDATE: Php code

```html
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbName = "shoppingcartdb";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbName);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO address (Address, PostalCode, City, County, Phone, Fax)
VALUES ('".$_POST["address"]."', '".$_POST["p_code"]."', '".$_POST["city_sector"]."', '".$_POST["county"]."', '".$_POST["phone"]."', '".$_POST["fax"]."')";
$conn->query($sql);
$sql = "CALL Insert_User('".$_POST["username"]."', '".$_POST["f_name"]."', '".$_POST["l_name"]."', '".$_POST["psw"]."', '".$_POST["email"]."')";
if(!$conn->query($sql))
 echo "failed";
$conn->close();
?>
```

UPDATE: Procedure
[Code ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jYhxW.png)

Comment: have you checked the profiler, if the query was executed on the server?

Comment: Looking at your updated php code, you do not need a stored proc at all. Just get the last inserted id after the address insertion via mysqli_insert_id() and just use a plain insert afterwards into users.

Comment: It worked! Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You have mixed up the input and local variables with session variables. `@id_add` is not the same as `id_add`, nor is `@f_name` the same ad `f_name`. Therefore you are trying to insert empty values into your table.
2. I cannot see on the screenshot if the delimiter was appropriatly set before and after the query. Pls check that.
3. Check the stored proc by testing it from phpmyadmin.

Comment: Hello! I am new in the world of php. I have just started to learn it. Can you give me a code exemple for "1."?

Comment: I just removed the @. The table still remains emty.

Comment: I've put an extra screenshot with the new Procedure

Comment: Ok, I hope I don't push up the limits but I have just searched how to test a Stored procedure in phpmyadmin and I didn't find anything concludent, I've just pushed the button go and a check sign appears. Point 2 I don't know what are you reffering to :)

Comment: You need to execute it from phpmyadmin with proper parameters. As to the 2nd point, search for mysql delimiter.

Comment: Updated procedure screenshot, hope you can figure it out whether or not I have the DELIMITER.

Comment: I've tested the procedure. It does not work. id_add value is NULL and can't figure out why.